# Oracle Trigger After Insert

Tags: database, oracle, triggers

I have a messages table. After an insert on messages, I need to insert the UserID and MsgID from that insert into the messageRecipient table. If the message was sent to a group, it needs to be inserted to every user that is a member of that group. Here is what I have, but it is not inserting into the messageRecipient table:

```
create or replace trigger update_messages
after insert on messages referencing new as new old as old  
for each row
declare 
      userID1 int(10);
      msgID1 int(10);
      groupID1 int(10);
begin
      userID1 := :new.ToUserID;
      msgID1 := :new.msgID;
      groupID1 := :new.ToGroupID;

     if inserting then
            if(userID1 <> null)
                then INSERT INTO messageRecipient VALUES(msgID1, userID1);
            elsif(groupID1 <> null)
                THEN INSERT INTO messageRecipient(msgID, userID) SELECT msgID1, userID FROM groupMembership WHERE gID = groupID1;
            end if;
     end if; 
end;
/
```

What exactly is going wrong here?

Comment: You're adding unnecessary complexity by assigning the :new values to variables. I'd start by removing them. Actually, if it was me I'd actually start by removing the trigger and implementing both the insert into the message table and the inserts into the recipient table with a single procedure, as triggers are notorious for making applications difficult to work with.

Answer (score 4):

```
create or replace trigger update_messages
-- after insert on messages referencing new as new old as old  
-- for each row

declare 
    userID1 int(10);
    msgID1 int(10);
    groupID1 int(10);
begin
    userID1 := :new.ToUserID;
    msgID1 := :new.msgID;
    groupID1 := :new.ToGroupID;

     if(userID1 is not null)
            then INSERT INTO messageRecipient VALUES(msgID1, userID1);
        elsif(groupID1 is not null)
            THEN INSERT INTO messageRecipient(msgID, userID) SELECT msgID1, userID FROM groupMembership WHERE gID = groupID1;
        end if;
 end;
```

Answer (score 3):

Comparing to `null` in PL/SQL will evaluate to `null`. And conditional statements execute only on `true`.
Check [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/isnull.php) for some reference.

Change `userID1 <> null` to `userID1 is not null` and `groupID1 <> null` to `groupID1 is not null`.

Also you don't need to add `if inserting` since this trigger is only for insert statement.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are checking the messageRecipient table from another session.
Remember that the trigger is part of the transaction that does the insert into messages table, therefore no changes are visible until a commit comes along.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you need to answer the question
'How do I work out what is going wrong here'

If you add an insert before your logic...

```
     INSERT INTO messageRecipient VALUES(msgID1, userID1);

     if inserting then.....
```

This would tell you the trigger is firing and it is picking up your new values

so it must be the comparison logic that is not working..

If you had a catch all condition you could raise an error and this would also allow you to see exactly where the problem is

```
if(userID1 is not null) then 
    INSERT INTO messageRecipient VALUES(msgID1, userID1);
elsif(groupID1 is not null) THEN 
    INSERT INTO messageRecipient(msgID, userID) 
        SELECT msgID1, userID FROM groupMembership WHERE gID = groupID1;
else
    RAISE ERROR HERE
 end if;
```